# Kafka: Discover brokers dynamically through Zookeeper

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am new to Kafka and exploring the options of dynamically discovering the brokers for a given topic through ZooKeeper rather than going with the static list of brokers. 
This is what i want to do,
1. For a given topic, get the list of partitions.
2. For each of the partitions, get the list of leader broker where the messages can be read.
3. Read the available messages of the topic from each of the brokers using the Simple Consumer.

Is this the right approach first of all? 
Does it make sense to read only from the leaders of the partition?
If so, are there any code samples for this?

Comment: This answers my question - https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/master/external/storm-kafka/src/jvm/storm/kafka/DynamicBrokersReader.java

Comment: Use the source of DynamicBrokersReader of Storm.

Above link gives 404, updated link: https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm-contrib/blob/master/storm-kafka/src/jvm/storm/kafka/DynamicBrokersReader.java

Comment: Yes, i did. Thanks